# Date range issue in MDX with missing dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas, mdx

I have an SSRS report which gets filtered with the following expression:

```
="{[Claim Cheque].[Cheque Date].&[" + format(Parameters!StartDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]:[Claim Cheque].[Cheque Date].&[" + format(Parameters!EndDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00:00]}"
```

which works fine. My problem is I don't have cheques everyday and this makes the query return no results. As an example I'm choosing the date range from 1st to 20th of November. I have cheques in 14th and 15th but NOT 20th. I will miss 14th and 15th results in my report this way.

I know how to force the parameters to get only existing values in the cube. but I need to be able to select all dates. Is there any other way to make this expression return desired results?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets filtered"? A Dataset filter? What do you mean by "I will miss 14th and 15th results"?

Comment: I apologize if the question was not clear, Mike. I'm using the expression above as Parameter Value in the Dataset in the SSRS Report. and I use the parameter as `... SELECT(STRTOSET(@myParameter))...` in the Dataset query. The `Parameters!StartDate` and `Parameters!EndDate` are Report Parameters. About the missing values in report result, my issue is that I'm manually creating an MDX Set with `Parameters!EndDate` = 20th of November which does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have a separate date dimension just for [Cheque Date], rather than linking back to a fully populated master date dimension. Take a look at the way Order Date and Ship Date dimensions are done in the AdventureWorks sample. They are explained nicely here: [Role-playing dimensions](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/11/role-playing-dimensions/)

I was able to run MDX queries like yours against that data, where there were no transactions on the start and end dates of the range:

```
Select 
[Measures].[Order Count] on 0,
[Sales Channel].&[Reseller] on 1
From [Adventure Works]
Where {[Ship Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20060701]:[Ship Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20060710]}
```

and

```
Select 
[Measures].[Order Count] on 0,
([Sales Channel].&[Reseller],
{[Ship Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20060701]:[Ship Date].[Fiscal].[Date].&[20060710]}) on 1
From [Adventure Works]
```